# Getting 400 bad request when trying to access an API using Angular, but it works perfectly fine when using PostMan

Tags: angular, api, http, postman, http-status-code-400

I have already tested this API and have made a GET request on the API using PostMan and got the response. But when trying to implement it on my Angular 6 application I get a 401 unauthorized error. This is my angular code.

```
this.http.get('https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/orders',{headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer *token*','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','cache-control':'no-cache'}})
.subscribe((response)=>{
  this.channel=response;
    console.log(this.channel)
})
}
```

I have the token and have not displayed it in the code for security reasons. I have a feeling it has something with the headers syntax but i'm not so sure.

Comment: Just check if the authentication mechanism is passed in headers in Postman where the header tab is different and you overlooked it... just in case...

Comment: Under the headers in Postman the key is 'Authorization' and the value is 'Bearer *token*. Everything seems to be exactly the same in Postman

Comment: I just reallized that I was making a post request on the api rather than a get. But now i'm getting another error. 400 bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you can try add them to your headers:

```
'authorization': 'bearer ' + token,
'Authenticationtoken': 'bearer ' + token,
'X-Requested-With'  : 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

My API used CakePHP3, same issue happen long ago, after added above 3 parameters everything ok :)

And more, please track your request by developer tools, and compare the difference between sucess and failed.